# How to deal with an unknown amount of query strings in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, url, express

I have a url that accepts an unknown number of query strings. Here is an example of a possible url

`/data/mydb.json?arg0="foo"&arg1=15&transaction=function(x, y)`

and the whole function body would be the rest of the url but I'll spare you the rest. The requests to `/data/:filename` will always accept the arguments and function as the query strings. Since req.query doesn't seem to take variables as an argument how can I deal with this? The function taken by the last query string will not always take 2 arguments. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of having arg<n>, use arg instead and it should become an array, making it easy to pass directly to the function using .apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to replace `arg0="foo"&arg1=15` with `args=["foo",15]`, then pass them in to the function with `.apply`.

If you know the names of the args, then you can use [req.query](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) to get the params. If you don't know the names and they need to be passed into the function in order, then you might have to use [req.originalUrl](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.originalUrl) and parse it manually, since you probably shouldn't trust that `req.query` will maintain the correct order of the params.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will know the names. They will always be arg0-some argument lets call it arg"n". Can I use req.query? As far as I can see you have to do req.query.something and this something cannot be a variable so I'm unsure how to do this.

Comment: `req.query` is a javascript object. So you can do something like `req.query.arg1` which in your example will be `"foo"`. If you need to access it with a variable you can do something like `var x="arg1"; req.query[x];` which will also be `"foo"`.

Comment: so could i do var args = [ ] and then req.query[i] in a for loop? something like that

Comment: If you had `var args = ["arg1", "arg2"]`, then you could do `req.query[args[i]]`